# If $M$ is a proper subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$, then there is a nonzero linear functional $f$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $f(M)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> If $M$ is a proper subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$, then there is a nonzero linear functional $f$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $f(M)=0$

I've tried to prove it by Hahn-Banach's theorem. Are  there any other simpler ways to prove it?

Comment: Projection onto $M^\perp$ is the obvious choice. Are you allowed to assume that $\mathbb{C}^n$ has an inner product?

Comment: M may not be closed!

Comment: Isn't  $\mathbbC^n$ finite dimensional though?

Comment: Yes, is your idea "decompose $\mathbb{C}^n=M\bigoplus M^\perp$?

Comment: Sure. Every subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ is closed because it is finite dimensional, hence for every subspace $M$, $\mathbb{C}^n=M\oplus M^\perp$.

Answer (score 5):

Pick a basis of $M$, extend to a basis of $\Bbb C^n$, define $f$ on that basis appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V = \Bbb C ^n / M$, the quotient space. Since $\Bbb C^n$ is finite-dimensional, so will be $V$, and $M$ will be closed, therefore $V$ will be Hausdorff. Briefly said, everything will be nice. Let $\pi : \Bbb C^n \to V$ be the natural projection. Let $\omega \in V^*$ be *any* linear form on $V$. Then $f = \omega \circ \pi : \Bbb C^n \to \Bbb C$ will be a linear form on $\Bbb C^n$ that vanishes on $M$: if $v \in M$, then by the mere definition of $\pi$ we shall have $\pi (v) = 0 \in V$, so $f(v) = 0 \in \Bbb C^n$.